How to batch-prove the knowledge of Module-SIS secrets
If the prover wishes to prove knowledge of Module-SIS secrets $\mathbf{s}_i$ satisfies $\mathbf{A}_i \cdot \mathbf{s}_i = \mathbf{u}_i\ \text{mos}\ q, i \in \{1,2,\cdots,N\}$ where $R_q$ is a polynomial ring, $\mathbf{A}_i \in R_q^{n \times m},\mathbf{s}_i \in R_q^{m},\mathbf{u} \in R_q^{n}$, can these instances be linearly combined using random challenges $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_{N} \in R_q$ from the verifier as:
$[\lambda_1\mathbf{A}_1|\lambda_2\mathbf{A}_2|\cdots|\lambda_N\mathbf{A}_N]\cdot\mathbf{s}=[\lambda_1\mathbf{u}_1|\cdots|\lambda_N\mathbf{u}_N]$ where $\mathbf{s} = \mathbf{s}_1||\mathbf{s}_2||\cdots||\mathbf{s}_N$ and $\lambda_i\mathbf{A}_i$ represents the result of multiplying each element in $\mathbf{A}_i$ by $\lambda$, and then proving knowledge of $\mathbf{s}$ with a small norm?
I'm not entirely sure whether the above proof method is reliable.
